# Easiest way to create a table with lots of columns in QT with SQL?

Tags: qt, qtsql

I'm going to create a table with these column names.

```
QStringList column_names = {"ID","Day","Hour","Minute","Second","Millisecond","ADC0","ADC1","ADC2","ADC3","ADC4","ADC5","ADC6","ADC7","ADC8","ADC9","ADC10","ADC11","DADC0","DADC1","DADC2","DADC3","DADC4","I0","I1","I2","I3","I4","I5","I6","I7","E0","E1","IC0","IC1","DAC0","DAC1","DAC2","PWM0","PWM1","PWM2","PWM3","PWM4","PWM5","PWM6","PWM7"};
```

There are different types of datatypes and some are floats.
But this makes the code quite messy if I'm going to use the `QSqlQuery` class in QT.

**Question:**

Do I need to use the `QSqlQuery` class to create a table with columns, or can I use `QSqlQueryModel` class in QT instead?

My goal is to create a table with the `column_names` above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**About QSqlQueryModel:**

After reviewing some of the online Qt documentation, it appears the only way to create a table using the `QSqlQueryModel` requires you to subclass `QSqlQueryModel`:
https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqlquerymodel.html#details

Otherwise, the interface of `QSqlQueryModel` does not perform write operations according to several locations in the documentation including:
https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqlquerymodel.html#setHeaderData

Another example of the behavior described according to a few people in a thread, as well as a brief description of a solution:
https://forum.qt.io/topic/35287/qsqltablemodel-read-only

Therefore, the existing means of using `QSqlQueryModel` as-is involves associating a view with the object instance, querying an existing database via the `QSqlQueryModel` instance, and displaying results of the query in the GUI.

**About using QSqlQuery instead:**

The implementation of `QSqlQuery` allows posting general queries to an SQL database, including poorly structured queries, read only queries, as well as write queries. Although the initialization process of a table with a large number
of columns you have listed seems annoying, it mostly depends on your use case of the database object.

**'Set and forget' use case:**

Assumptions for this use case include: infrequent or singularly large amounts of data being added every now and then, primarily reads from the database.

Use the `QSqlQuery` interface to perform your writes to the database, as well as a `QSqlQueryModel` for the GUI(if any). The idea is you will be rarely calling the `QSqlQuery` interface anyway, when the query is completed, you can simply
refresh the `QSqlQueryModel` object, as well as its corresponding view in a lock step manner. Although this solution seems less cohesive than using one or the other it will be easier to thread this kind of setup because then you
could pass a `QSqlQuery` object around wrapped in a command class usable to the remainder of your own application.

Additionally, the `QSqlQueryModel` instance would provide the view object, whatever that is, with incremental rows, no need to hand roll that using `QSqlQuery`.

**'Legacy dataset handling' use case:**

Assumptions for this use case include: never updating the underlying dataset.

Use the `QSqlQueryModel` exclusively. If writing is really necessary subclass `QSqlQueryModel`. Although make sure to avoid exposing an easy means of passing in the "DROP" SQL reserve word by accident/error on the users part.

**'High throughput' use case:**

No easy solution for this one. Highly dependent on use case metrics, and other items. Perhaps sticking with `QSqlQuery` is recommended here if the tables are frequently accessed or sorted against common columns is best if the application is threaded very well. Each thread would get a connection as well as all the necessary query objects to execute.

However, having a simplified, easy to refresh, read-only view object, such as `QSqlQueryModel` in conjunction with the `QSqlQuery` objects getting passed around, or generated seems like a good idea all around.

Clearly this use case requires more testing, and information on your part to give you a better answer.

**IMPORTANT(all use cases):**

You don't have to specify every single column name in every `QSqlQuery` or call to `QSqlQueryModel`. If you will need to request a large number of column names in general, use maps/pairs to return categories of related names from the
list of names provided. So for example, the "PWM#" names could be contained in a pair that returns all the strings of a similar name. Then run a for loop to append the returned values to a SQL query you are going to execute.

I'm sure there are a few good fast substring search options out there as well to help you out. Then you could just quickly search for a header name in a string you store in a wrapper class of your design that supports the desired functionality.

Could you provide more information about your use case that requires submitting a large number of column names at the same time?

I can think of a better solution, possibly some code as well, if there is a better explanation of the types of queries you will be submitting, memory constraints, and or speed concerns.

Based on your question I am assuming you are C++?

Comment: Great! A prototype solution I would use for your use case involves writing a class to wrap the Qt objects in question, add some auxiliary data members such as the map object/pairs I mentioned above if the table manager wrapper does not need to be too complicated. At that point add a parent string of the header data. Write some functions to separate the column names into relevant containers. Reference the containers in your code when submitting queries to the target database instance. Please provide more information if you want a more specific solution. Such as, what needs to be dynamic?

Comment: Thanks, but I'm totaly beginner in QT framework and I need to explore it more until I can determine what I need to do. Right now I'm looking for QT solution for JSON. I'm building a logger in embedded C + STM32 + numerical methods etc. + SAE J1939 canbus

Comment: See here https://github.com/DanielMartensson/CControl

Comment: Super cool project! Question, what is the specific microcontroller in the image on the github link you sent? Also how much memory does it support? I tried looking it up using the identifiers on the board but was having a hard time.

Comment: No specific microcontroller at all. You can use this at any system because this C code is written with no external libraries. Only standard libraries and the code does not take account which hardware you are using.